# Unable to import python requests library into AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a lambda function that where I cannot the requests library to import.

So far I have tried the following imports:

```
import requests
from botocore.vendored import requests
```

Neither of these has worked. Other libraries are importing fine such as import json.

What do I need to do to get the requests library to import to AWS Lambda

Comment: requests library doesn't come by default in lambda. Comment out the first line and just have the second line.

Comment: Ah yea, that worked. There was an issue with my URL being bad which I confused with the library not importing. Thanks.

Comment: I am going to add that as the answer. If it works, please accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

requests library doesn't come by default in lambda. Comment out the first line and just go with the second line:

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
```